# Similarity between two matrices

Tags: matrix, similarity

what is the best way to compare two matrices to see if they are similar or not? I have two 12*12 matrices, in which the values are cosine similarities between pairs of words. I want to calculate the similarity between these two matrices ( have tried correlations such as Pearson, spearman, Kendell and I know that these matrices are similar, but the values from these correlations are not very high.)
Do you know some other ways? I also tried the Mantel test (which is performing on distance matrices, but the results still not satisfying!)

Answer (score 0):

have you checked for the eigenvalues? you could also use the quantile rank method